# Updating @Published var if a userdefault value is present swift

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to check my app and see if a value exists in user defaults and if it does exist they will be taken into the app. If it doesnt exist they need to enter there pin and then get into the app.

Any idea how to check if a value is present in user defaults and then change isValidated to true

// main

```
import SwiftUI
@main
struct ProjectHogtieApp: App {
    @StateObject var authentication = Authentication()
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if authentication.isValidated {
                ContentView()
                    .environmentObject(authentication)
            } else {
                LoginView()
                    .environmentObject(authentication)
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

// authentiction.swift

```
class Authentication: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isValidated = false
    
    // this code is not working.
    var getIsValidated: Void {
        let deviceId = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "deviceId")
        if (deviceId != nil) {
            self.isValidated = true
        } else {
            self.isValidated = false
        }
    }
```

When the user enters there pin, I save the value in user defaults as shown below

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
defaults.set(deviceId, forKey: "deviceId")
```

Comment: Look into @AppStorage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, to check your `UserDefaults` when the App starts (ie. when `Authentication` is created):

```
class Authentication: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var isValidated = false
    
    // --- here
    init() {
        getIsValidated
    }
  //....
```

Note that for important things like authentication etc... you should be using `Keychain` to save data securely, not `UserDefaults`

Comment: This worked perfect. Exactly what I was looking for. I did make it into a separate function instead of computed property in the initializer. Thank you. Also thank you for mentioning the userDefaults and storing authentication. My app doesn't have any private info so thats why I am using defaults. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

You can continue down the path you're going. However, there exists a property wrapper in `SwiftUI` known as `AppStorage`. This is essentially a convenience wrapper to get and set values in `UserDefaults`. In this case, you might use it like this...

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct ProjectHogtieApp: App {

    @AppStorage("isAuthenticated") private var isAuthenticated: Bool = false

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if isAuthenticated {
                ContentView()
            } else {
                LoginView()
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

The parameter taken by the property wrapper is your key, and the value you provide is the default value, but will be overwritten by any existing value in `UserDefaults`.

Comment: Was unaware of appStorage. It worked using it this way but the initializers flows better with what I have. Thanks for the advice tho